# How to Stop a requireJS Module from Loading

Tags: requirejs

What is a good strategy for stopping a requireJS module from loading from information you won't know until run-time?

The scheme I came up with involves using a loader plug-in that checks some run-time attributes and checks the "protected" modules against their attribute lists, and if they're not supposed to load, doesn't call load() from inside the loader plug-in load() function. However, this results in a browser error, which in older versions of IE, cause actual script errors, which is not what I want/need (it's actually a time-out error because load() is never called).

Is there a way to say, "Yeah, I got that you wanted to load this, but, um, we don't want to, and that's not an error, so go about your business with the rest of your loading business."  Or perhaps a better scheme to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing load(null) and checking for null in the places where the module that could possibly not be loaded is referenced.